# __sub__ on set of strings in Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, set, operators

Can someone explain me the behavior of Python 2.7 here? (and also a more robust alternative if possible)

```
>>> base = set(['blub', 'a'])
>>> print base - set('a')
set(['blub'])
>>> print base - set('blub')
set(['a', 'blub']) # wtf?
```

Could not find any answer to this, sorry.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to to with they way python handles strings for the creation of sets. The difference:

```
>>> base = set(['blub', 'a'])
>>> set('a')
set(['a'])
>>> set('blub')
set(['b', 'u', 'l'])
```

As you can see, python interprets each character of the string as single entry in the set, therefore the operation does not work as expected.

If you change `set('blub')` to `set(['blub'])`, the set gets created as expected, and the operation works.

```
>>> set(['blub'])
set(['blub'])
>>> print base - set('a')
set(['blub'])
>>> print base - set(['blub'])
set(['a'])
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that!